# Can somebody identify my bike for me?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike, used-bike

I got it as a sort of hand me down a couple of years ago.  I think that it is from the late 90s or early 2000s.  It is definitely a mountain bike and it is red and silver/gray.  It is hard to pick out any defining characteristics because the seat and shocks are aftermarket and there are stickers all over the frame...any ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not necessarily a BSO, but it's pretty generic, and nothing screams "expensive".  Looks like a perfectly serviceable bike, though.

Comment: Well to be honest I think it's a straight mountain bike and I'm looking to get rid of it in favor of a hybrid or street bike.  I find that it doesn't work all that well on the road...like if I stop pedaling it stops moving...It's meant for off road and that's not what I need so I'm trying to sell it, but it's hard to market a bike that you don't even have a brand name for.

Comment: If it stops moving when you stop pedaling something's dragging.  Could just be underinflated tires, or could be brakes or something else.  (Plus of course lugged tires are not the best idea on the road.)  The only thing that makes it not a passable road bike is the shock fork, and that can be locked out, by hook or by crook.

Comment: Thank you do much...I am like..below beginner level on bikes and I'm used to pedal pedal pedal coast...and on this it's like pedal pedal stop...so I was pushing the whole time...I assumed it was because it's a mountain bike and maybe that's just how they are if they're meant for offroading

Comment: No, a mountain bike should roll about as well as any other, aside from the drag due to the lugged tires.  The front shock (if not "locked") does make pedaling somewhat less efficient, but that has no effect on how well the bike rolls.

Comment: I think you somehow dropped an image and duplicated another. The tags are 2,3,4 and 3 was duplicated. Missing 1.

Comment: Looks like it says "Giant" in the downtube under all those stickers. That's a reputable bike company, so most likely not a BSO if that's what it says.

Comment: Looks like a halfway-decent bike that just needs a little maintenance. Lift the rear end, spin the wheel forward. It should spin freely. If it doesn't, then something is dragging - most likely the brakes. Repeat with the front wheel. If you need help adjusting the brakes so they don't drag, come back here and post a question.

Comment: Assuming those rockshox stickers are real (and it doesn't look like a BSO fork so I think it is), its definitely not a BSO. My guess is its one of the lower end Giant's. Maybe something like a Boulder SE or something -- I'm pretty sure I've seen that paint job on the Giant model right above the Boulder, but I can't remember which one it is. You should be able to pull the serial from the bike though and ask Giant.

Comment: You can probably peel off the stickers with some work, and then figure out what kind of bike it is anyway.

Comment: The visible height of the suspension fork implies that its got a bit more travel than a cheap bike.  If you can lock out the suspension, and fit some harder smoother tyres/tires you'll have a workable hybrid/commuter bike.   Fix whatever is dragging and it will be easier to ride and will be doing less damage to itself.

Comment: What is that silly looking bolt-on bar across the handlebars?  Some kind of aftermarket stiffener ?

Comment: Seriously thank all of you guys so much you have helped me a lot...I was well on my way to going to buy a new bike but it sounds like I may not have to do that...you've all been so much help!

Comment: @Criggie "hardpoint" for handlebar mounted stuff I would guess. Looks quite useful for flashlight (centered and level,

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the stickers it might help show you any branding.

It LOOKS like a reasonably decent, slightly old school mountain bike. The kind worth handing down. People are debating if its a BSO. This means Bike Shaped Object, which is derogatory term for rubbish bikes sold in supermarkets etc.

It looks better than that, branded forks and decent derailleurs, good headset, but should be easier to ride than you commented. Pick up the bike and spin the wheels. If they stop quickly there's a problem, with the brakes and/or with the bearings.

If you take it to a bike shop, they can help identify it and tell you what it's worth. They can get it rolling like new again. I would recommend some slicker tyres if you want to ride on the road - but keep the suspension for rough roads and potholes!